# Second time FPDF runs, crashes

Tags: python, fpdf

I use the code below to generate monthly reports. When I need to get reports of two different months, the first month is created correctly, then I change the month and restart the program. Upon output, fpdf crashes with the traceback you see below
To get the two months' reports I have to create the first report, completely exit the py program, restart and create the second report.

From what I see in the traceback it doesn't seem to find any images, but they are the same ones used for the first report

```
class Build_Pdf(FPDF):

    table = ''
pdf = FPDF('L', 'mm', 'A4')
pdf.alias_nb_pages()

def top(year, meonth, table):
    pdf.add_font('IndieFlower-Regular', '', '/usr/.local/share/fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf', uni=True)
    write_year = 'Reference: ' + month + ' ' + year
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image('/opt/rambo/logo.jpg', 25, 8, 30)
    pdf.set_font('IndieFlower-Regular', '', 15)
    pdf.set_y(50)
    pdf.set_x(15)
    pdf.cell(50, 7, write_year, 0, 1, 'L')
    pdf.image('/opt/rambo/gg.png', 65, 30, 15)
    return



def create_Pdf(year, month):
    global error, none
    month = Functions.convert_month_number[month]
    check = check_table(year, month, daysinmonth, table = 'timetable')
    if check is not 0:
        go_Pdf (year, month, table = 'timetable')
    [...]
    pdffile = '/media/hdb1/temp/Location.pdf'
    if os.path.exists(pdffile):
        os.remove(pdffile)
    pdf.output(pdffile, 'F')
    pdf.close()
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
    msg.setText("Pdf file is in /media/hdb1/temp/Location.pdf")
    msg.exec_()
    return
    
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../PycharmProjects/SecondOne/index.py", line 333, in MakePdf
    Create_Pdf(year, month)
  File "../PycharmProjects/SecondOne/makepdfhour_data.py", line 86, in Create_Pdf
    pdf.output(pdffile, 'F')
  File ".../fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1065, in output
    self.close()
  File ".../fpdf/fpdf.py", line 246, in close
    self._enddoc()
  File ".../fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1637, in _enddoc
    self._putresources()
  File ".../fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1585, in _putresources
    self._putimages()
  File ".../fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1515, in _putimages
    del info['data']
KeyError: 'data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a constructor to your class like the below code and it will work.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.table = ''
    self.pdf = FPDF('L', 'mm', 'A4')
    self.pdf.alias_nb_pages()
```